# “Package file was not signed correctly” error upon installation

Tags: android, keytool, jarsigner

I created an Android app and published it within the Google Play Store.  Upon subsequent download, I receive the “Package file was not signed correctly” error.  I investigated and found the entry:

[Published Android apk gives error "Package file was not signed correctly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519374/published-android-apk-gives-error-package-file-was-not-signed-correctly)

I tried the JDK 6 solution (compile and sign under JDK 6) but there was no joy.  I tried to download/install on both a 2.3.3 and 4.x device but neither would work.  In my case, the app was new so the keystore is also (not an update) new.  I will say that the new keystore was initially created under JDK 1.7.

I am stumped on how to approach resolving this issue, anyone have thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Published Android apk gives error "Package file was not signed correctly"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519374/published-android-apk-gives-error-package-file-was-not-signed-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this issue in the past. If you're using different folders for your layouts (for different screen size and different languages), can you check that the default folder for each resource is present ?
(basically you need to have a folder res/drawable, res/layout, res/values etc... even if they're empty)

Comment: Yes, they exist.  In addition, one of the apps is brand new (never been deployed to the App Store before) so it has no history.  The common thread across all three is the error message.

Comment: The only major difference was the addition of ActionBarSherlock as a library.