# 2 Apps, 1 keystore, only one works

Tags: android, google-play

I recently published 2 apps tot the Play market of android.
I signed both(from within netbeans) with the same keystore and same alias.
The first [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.tjenwellens.timetracker) I signed works as it should, the [other](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.tjenwellens.pairtester) gives the error "android package file was not signed correctly" when trying to install from market.

Any ideas as to what is wrong are appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Published Android apk gives error "Package file was not signed correctly"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519374/published-android-apk-gives-error-package-file-was-not-signed-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have used the wrong key/alias when signing the file.

Source: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120663/how-do-you-resolve-or-troubleshoot-package-file-not-signed-correctly-error-from-android-app-in-market-place

You should also verify that you don't have the debug copy still installed on your device.

Source: [Published Android apk gives error "Package file was not signed correctly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519374/published-android-apk-gives-error-package-file-was-not-signed-correctly)

Comment: Aah, yeah. indead the debug version was still installed.

Comment: @TjenWellens If my answer was correct, please mark it as such by clicking the green check next to my answer.

Comment: I was trying when I commented but I couldn't because of some delay. But there you go.
Thanks again!