# "Package file was not signed correctly" error when Android app auto-updates

Tags: android

Android (4.3) notifications show that several apps are attempting to auto-update but all are failing with an error saying "Package file was not signed correctly".  This happens repeated (over several days) for several apps.

Possibly related: I installed a newer ROM (4.4) after doing a factory reset and then reverted to 4.3 from a nandroid backup. The problem noted here seemed to start after reverting the ROM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Published Android apk gives error "Package file was not signed correctly"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519374/published-android-apk-gives-error-package-file-was-not-signed-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

The app may be uninstalled but still appearing on the app list as 'uninstalled'. I don't think the clear cache option appears in this case so you could also try going to Settings >> Apps, select that app, and click "Uninstall for all users".

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache for the Google Play Store app seems to fix this problem. Go into Settings >> Apps, select that app, and click "Clear cache".