# Packaged Not Signed Correctly Error When Downloading APK after Signing with JDK8

Tags: android, google-play, apk, keytool, signing

Using the keytool tool in the JDK 8, I signed my APK and successfully uploaded it to the play store. However, once I downloaded it, it said, "Package was not signed correctly". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have your debug version of application still installed on your
>   device?

If yes, Now you have downloaded a different copy of the same app and it's causing this error.

Uninstall the app completely from your device. Then download it from the market again and it might work.

Another reason

I did a quick research and In Many links and Blogs, people seem to have faced the similar issue and they have started using jdk 6 and signed their app and uploaded to playstore again.

[Published Android apk gives error "Package file was not signed correctly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519374/published-android-apk-gives-error-package-file-was-not-signed-correctly)

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146110/my-app-gives-package-file-was-not-signed-correctly-error-on-google-play-store

http://support.ludei.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200781567-Google-Play-error-Package-file-was-not-signed-correctly-

Hope this information helps.

Comment: I deleted the debug version before I downloaded it.